# Find the number of zeros, counting multiplicity, of $z^8 -z^3 +10$ inside the first quadrant $\{z\in \Bbb C: \Bbb R e(z)>0,\Bbb Im(z)>0 \}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Find the number of zeros, counting multiplicity, of $z^8 -z^3 +10$ inside the first quadrant $\{z\in \Bbb C: \Bbb R e(z)>0,\Bbb Im(z)>0 \}$.

I'm assuming to use Rouche's theorem or argument principle, but how to use?

Comment: Rouche's is definitely the way to go. What I would do is use quarter circles as your path You might have some cases to consider depending on which term dominates.

Comment: The coefficients are real, so the zeros are symmetric with respect to the real line. Count the zeros in the right half-plane, $z^8 + 10$ is helpful.

Comment: @DanielFischer So I just calculated that if we choose the polynomial $z^8 + 10$, there are 4 roots on the right half plane. Since they are symmetric, we should have 2 roots in the first quadrant?

Comment: Aye, that's correct. Of course the argument why $z^8 + 10$ and $z^8 - z^3 + 10$ have the same number of zeros in the right half-plane (and none of them is real) must also be made.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, that's right.

Comment: @DanielFischer I also have another similar question: Find the number of distinct zeros of $f(z)=z^6 +(10-i)z^4 +1$ inside $(-1,1) \times (-1,1)$. When we have complex number coefficients, how should we deal with this?

Comment: That's a direct application of Rouché's theorem, just pick the right dominating term, then look that $f$ has only simple zeros.

Comment: @DanielFischer Can we pick $(10-i)z^4$ here? It seems the result is the same if we use a unit disc to replace $(-1,1) \times (-1,1)$.

Comment: @Topoguy Yes, $\lvert (10-i)z^4\rvert \geqslant \lvert 10-i\rvert > 10 > 9 = 1 + (\sqrt{2})^6 \geqslant \lvert z^6+1\rvert$ on the boundary of the square.